# How to Keep Blackberry Socket Connections Alive in an app with an Instant Message Feature

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am having problems keeping a socket connection in my application alive for a long period. It seems to disconnect after a short while (every 2 minutes) especially if idle.

It happens that I am writing an application with a Chat feature and this requires I keep a socket connection Alive for the life-tme of my application. I have already tried tricks like pinging server every minute, but then this constitute a drain of (Blackberry) resources. Blackberry Push isnt an option (as i have other clients other than BB devices).

Please does anyone know how I can solve this or still suggest another alternative way of going about this?

[also i am interested in how instant messaging cross-mobile platform apps like WhatsApp, Kiks, etc manage to pull this off without excessively draining resources (at least my Resource Monitor App doesnt cry foul]

Answer (score 1):

We found same behavior with socket connection on several BB OS versions. We tried to play with socket connection options - timeout supported, timeout value, etc. But we didn't find anything reliable and workable on all platforms consistent.

So we ended up with next configuration:

1. Devices with push - keep socket open with pinging after inactivity timeout switch to the push
2. Devices without push - keep socket with longest available ping

Case 2 is mush rare and as well we selected longest the longest ping interval that keeps connection open. It doesn't work 100%, we saw that on some devices it still drops the connection. But we carefully handle this case with reopening new one.

Hope this helps. Success!

Answer (score 1):

> Blackberry Push isnt an option (as i have other clients other than BB devices).

It's complicated, but popular apps definitely take advantage of BlackBerry push, as well as push functionality offered on all the other mobile platforms.  It's part of supporting BlackBerry "for real" not just as an afterthought.  The short answer for you is to use the BlackBerry push service.